After the introduction of the activity7 component in SpringBoot, when the project starts, the backend crazily queries the database
When my springboot started, the backend kept printing MySQL SQL statements. I saw that they were all library operations in the activity process engine, including query and delete operations. The project interface could be accessed, but it was very resource intensive. I don't know why
Don't keep having database operations after the project starts



